# How can I write a list of objects to firebase?

Tags: android, list, firebase, arraylist

I am trying to write multiple nodes at one go in Firebase, my data class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Data{
    public String desc;
    public double id;
    public data(String desc,double id) {
        this.id=id;
        this.desc=desc;
    }
}
```

And I am trying this

```
   .....//firebase auth ok

    ArrayList<Data> mydata= new ArrayList<>();
    mydata.add(new Items("data1",1));
    mydata.add(new Items("data2",2));                               
    mDatabase.child("DATA").setValue(mydata);
```

But this fails as firebase doesn't support Listarray I guess, as I am getting the error

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to
>   serialize found on class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are directly setting value at the root level.
Just Try by creating another child inside the root node.

```
List<Data> mydata= new ArrayList<>();
mydata.add(new Data("data1",1));
mydata.add(new Data("data2",2));                               
mDatabase.child("DATA").child("CHILD NAME").setValue(mydata);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case, as I actually simplified my code above and removed the extra node I already have.

Comment: This is how I am doing and its working fine. Here tripCollection is an ArrayList            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(Const.USER_TRIPS).child(uuid).child(tripCollection.getPnr()).setValue(tripCollection);

Comment: Is your tripCollection an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes tripCollections is an ArrayList<Trip>

Answer (score 0):

First of all **your constructor from your model si wrong**, needs to be `Data` in stead of data. You getting such an error because you are using a `List` in stead of an `Map`. Change this line of codes:

```
ArrayList<Data> mydata= new ArrayList<>();
mydata.add(new Items("data1",1));
mydata.add(new Items("data2",2));                               
mDatabase.child("DATA").setValue(mydata);
```

with

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference pushedKey = mDatabase.child("DATA").push();
Data data = new Data("data1", 1));                             
pushedKey.setValue(data);
```

In this way you'll have also different keys for every new object.

Hope it helps.